# Uploading file gets bad request error in flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to upload a file from angular as frontend to flask as backend, but every time I upload a file I always get an error like the following

```
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'flag_icon'
```

I've tried several ways from the internet and youtube but still can't find the solution, can anyone help me?

Here's the HTML form in angular that I'm using

```
  <form class="form-body" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="flag_icon">{{used_lang.lable_currflag}}</label>
      <input class="form-control form-control-lg mb-3" 
      type="file" 
      id="flag_icon" 
      name="flag_icon" 
      (change)="flagIconChange($event)"
      accept="image/*"
      disabled
      required>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Here's the program code that I wrote in the ts file

```
  flagIconChange(event: any) {
    const file:File = event.target.files[0];

    if (file) {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("flag_icon", file);
      this.backendAPI.flagIconUpdate(formData).subscribe((res: any) => {console.log(res)});
    }
  }
```

The following is the program code for the service API that I use

```
  uploadFile = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Pragma': 'no-cache',
      "Accept": "multipart/form-data"
    })
  } 

  flagIconUpdate(data: any): Observable<any>{
    return this.httpClient.post(this.baseAPI + '/forex/flag_icon', data, this.uploadFile)
    .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }
```

Here's the program code on flask

```
@app.route('/forex/flag_icon', methods=['POST'])
def forexFlagIconUpload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       flag_name = request.files["flag_icon"]
       return jsonify({'status': flag_name.filename}),200
```

Comment: try : `@app.route('/forex/flag_icon/', methods=['POST'])`  don't forget the  `/` after flag icon

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but try to use `request.form["flag_icon"]` instead of `request.files["flag_icon"]` as you are sending a form with the file inside as a input

```
@app.route('/forex/flag_icon', methods=['POST'])
def forexFlagIconUpload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       flag_name = request.files["flag_icon"]
       return jsonify({'status': flag_name.filename}),200
```

to:

```
@app.route('/forex/flag_icon', methods=['POST'])
def forexFlagIconUpload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       flag_name = request.files["flag_icon"]
       return jsonify({'status': flag_name.filename}),200
```